# difference between parameter __local and within-kernel __local in OpenCL

Tags: local, opencl

Sometimes openCL kernels have in their parameters

```
kernel someName (some globalparameters, __local int* myArray) {
```

while other scripts have somewhere inside the kernel

```
__local int myArray[length];
```

what is the difference between these? I thought they were only syntactic differences, but now I see inside one of the official AMD samples (RadixSort) the comment

```
__local KV_TYPE localDataArray[TPG*4*2]; // Faster than using it as a parameter !!!
```

so apparently I was wrong. And effectively, when I try it in my scripts it goes faster. Buy why? Aren't both supposed to be simply array pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the performance issue, but the primary difference is not mere syntax. Passing a local buffer as a parameter allows the size to be determined at runtime. Defining the buffer in the kernel itself requires the size to be known at compile time.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's the disadvantage of hardcoding it. The compiler indeed has some extra info. But my question is how the compiler ever manages to take advantage of this, even to the level it causes a 12% speed increase in my code.

Comment: Maybe looking at the code generated by the compiler might yield some clues.

Comment: Of course, I see ample differences, but I would lie if I said I understand what's going on. I hope someone has a plausible theoretical explaining of the larger picture, as I'm mainly trying to understand the principles behind it.